# Behave print all tests to a text file

Tags: python-behave

I have been asked to provide a list of every behave Feature and Scenario we run as part of our regression pack for a document to an external client (not the steps)

As our regression test suite is currently around 50 feature files with at least 10 scenarios in each I would rather not copy and paste manually.

Is there a way to export the Feature name and ID and then the name and ID of each scenario that comes under that feature either to a CSV or text file?

Currently our behave tests are run locally and I am using PyCharm IDE to edit them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a roundabout way to do this.

Set Behave to export to an external txt file using the command
outfiles = test_list

Then use the behave -d command to run my tests as a dry run. 
This then populates the txt file with the feature, scenario and step of every test. 
I can export this to Excel and through filtering can isolate the feature and scenario lines removing the steps and then use text to columns to split the feature/scenario description from its test path/name.

If there is a less roundabout way of doing this it would be good to know as it looks like this is information we will need to be able to provide on a semi regular basis moving forwards.

Comment: As yours is a custom requirement, i would call this as a solution rather than workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of context.scenario to get scenario name and feature name and then write them into a text file.
You should put these code in after_scenario in environment.py so that you also can get the scenario status.

I am using this for export scenario name, status and feature name into a text file. Each will be separated by "|". I later import this file to a excel file for reporting.

Here is the code you can use for reference:

```
def write_scenario_summary(context, scenario, report_path):
    try:
    # scenario status could be [untested, skipped, passed, failed]
        status = scenario.compute_status().name.upper()
        feature = ReportingHelper.get_feature_name(scenario)
        logging_info = '{status} | {feature} | | {scenario_name}'.format(
        status=status,
        feature=feature,
        scenario_name=scenario.name)
    print(logging_info, file=open(report_path, 'a'))


def get_feature_name(scenario):
    feature_file_path = scenario.feature.filename
    return os.path.basename(feature_file_path)
```

Hope it helps.